# As the picture depicted, which is right？

Tags: integration

[image]

This is really an easy question,but I am puzzled with that which one is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct:

$$\int\limits_0^z\frac{d\zeta}{1-\zeta} = -\int\limits_1^{1-z}\frac{d\omega}{\omega}=\int\limits_{1-z}^{1}\frac{d\omega}{\omega}$$

Because

$\omega = 1 - \zeta$

$\zeta = 1 - \omega, d\zeta = -d\omega$

$\omega = 0 \Rightarrow \zeta = 1$

$\omega = z \Rightarrow \zeta = 1 - z$

Comment: Can you give more formulas in detail?

Comment: Ok, I've changed my post, any questions?

Comment: Thank you.I have understood.Do you know about Fourier analysis?I have two questions about Fourier analysis without any explanation,and you can check my question list.